# Is it possible to set a TitledBorder opaque on Swing?

Tags: java, swing, opacity, titled-border

Is it somehow possible on Swing to set a TitledBorder transparent so that a background image shines through?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, got confused within my own thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

Use the method

```
setOpaque(false)
```

on the underlying panel.

Answer (score 0):

Strange - [TitledBorder.isBorderOpaque()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#isBorderOpaque()) supposedly returns `false`, so it should already work. Maybe the problem is just that the component you're putting the border on just doesn't paint the background image over the border insets?